# Are retags of [twitter-bootstrap] to version-specific tags okay?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw [some suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6049279) in the review queue, where different users removed [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and added [twitter-bootstrap-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-2) or [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) instead. I know that there is a lot of [discussion about bootstrap tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited).

So what's the current code of conduct?

1. Remove [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) and add a version-specific tag.
2. Keep both tags.
3. Remove version-specific tags and add [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

P.S.: There is a similar [meta discussion about C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274921/if-i-use-c11-tag-do-i-also-have-to-use-c-tag), but I'm not sure if the answer applies here too, because it is said that bootstrap 3 isn't backward compatible.

Comment: I think [tag:twitter-bootstrap] should always be there to attract those members who follow that tag. A specific tag [tag:twitter-bootstrap-x] should be there is if solution for that specific version x is required. I think it doesn't make sense to list all variants of [tag:twitter-bootstrap-x] if the required solution should be version independent, here [tag:twitter-bootstrap] should be used.

Comment: @honk the issue with bootstrap is that the solution is NOT version independent.  They are not backwards compatible.  2 and 3 are vastly different. see the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: @basher: If there is no solution (to whatever problem) that would be the same for [tag:twitter-bootstrap-2] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3], then [tag:twitter-bootstrap] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-2] should always be applied for version 2 and [tag:twitter-bootstrap] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3] should always be applied for version 3.

Comment: Hasn't the _twitter_ been dropped from the name, anyway? Maybe twitter-bootstrap-2 and bootstrap-3 is the right combination.