# Should the [c++] tag be mandatory for posts with C++ language version tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The C++ language has gone through several revisions, in particular [C++98](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization), [C++03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03), [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14), [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), and [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), and there are tags for each of these versions ([c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98), [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), and [c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), respectively).

As far as I can tell, there is no reason to ever use one of these version tags for a question without [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) applying to it as well. In fact, each of the language version wikis say to use [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in addition to the version tag.

Despite this, many such posts are not tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and at the moment there are about 8,000 of them. These are only the currently incorrectly tagged questions, but there are many that are corrected daily by watchers of the language version tags.

There are a number of issues I see with this, in decreasing order of importance:

1. There aren't many watchers of version specific tags, and as a result, many good quality questions simply don't get the attention they deserve.
2. A fair amount of energy is expended on retagging such posts, usually by watchers of the language version tags. If I had to make a rough guess, on average I personally add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) to about half a dozen such questions every day, and I'm aware of other users who do this quite a lot as well.
3. Duplicates that are incorrectly tagged can't be closed by gold tag badge holders if they add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) themselves. This dilutes the effectiveness of the duplicate-hammer, and there aren't as many gold tag badge holders as one would ideally like, and so obvious duplicates can go hours, if not longer, without being closed.

One potential concern is the limit of five tags that can be added to a question. In practice, I haven't found this to be much of an issue, since usually at least one of the other tags is incorrect, or redundant.

Is it a good idea to make [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) be automatically added to any post with a language version tag? Perhaps the OP could be asked to remove one of the other tags if they already have five, or the limit could be waived when a combination of these tags is used.

I can't see any downside to this approach, other than it being potentially difficult to implement (I can't speak to that).

Comment: Similarly, the [tag:python] tag is often missed off Python questions which have a version-specific tag instead. I imagine similar things happen with lots of languages.

Comment: @khelwood Then it might make sense to do something similar for python? I don't know enough about python to say if that's the right approach. e.g. knowing python3 doesn't mean one automatically knows python2 I think.

Comment: But I think any question tagged with python 3 should automatically be tagged with python.

Comment: @10Rep Yes, I think I agree with that particular example. I would be wary of simply applying this to all language tags that have version tags though. There might be valid cases where the base language tag is *not* appropriate (though I can't think of an example off the top of my head).

Comment: Most of the time people using a version-specific Python tag are not asking version-specific questions and should have used the plain python tag instead. I presume the ui has presented them with the version-specific tag and they didn't bother reading the usage advice. If the ui would stop suggesting them it would alleviate that problem. I don't know to what extent all that applies to C++ questions.

Comment: @khelwood That would just be a mistag then, right? I don't think there's a way of preventing that automatically (even in c++). I'm not sure, but I don't think c++ questions get suggested version specific tags.

Comment: You're discovering what's sometimes considered the problem of version tags. Since the language is included in the version tag, whether it's [tag:c++20], [tag:ecmascript-6], or [tag:python-3.x], including the base language tag too is indeed *redundant*, which is why some choose not to/ forget, but it's also still beneficial because of tag watchers.

Comment: @zcoop98 Beneficial therefore not redundant.

Comment: Almost exact duplicate: [If I use C++11 tag do I also have to use C++ tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274921/if-i-use-c11-tag-do-i-also-have-to-use-c-tag)

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica It's not a dupe at all. It's asking if [c++] should be added to a post with a version tag. My question takes that for granted, and asks if the process should/could be automated.

Comment: Same goes for the [swift tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399146/which-swift-tag-should-i-use). Also, congrats on gaining 37k reputation whilst still being a new contributor.

Comment: Sometimes one doesn't even know if languages have versions and can't tell if a problem is caused by its version rather than some other thing.

Comment: @0-1 that "new contributor" thing is a meta bug :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not a bug, you just get separate new contributor icons for main/meta, and they _are_ a new contributor to meta :)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala New contributor seems correct, this is my first post on meta. Meta works differently than Main, so a high rep user may make beginner mistakes on meta, so I'm glad the signal exists :)

Comment: Good Q. Many times a version spec C++ tag is used w/o good motive. F.ex. when a Q about MT is tagged w/ the 1st C++ std that has MT support. Well, duh, you aren't asking about the use of `std::mutex` for a C++ std that didn't even have `std::mutex`. Who would have guessed?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It would be nice, yes, for all of the reasons you cited.

Unfortunately, the platform simply doesn't support it. There's no facility for "mandatory" or "implied" tags.

While I remain unpersuaded by the more complex "tag hierarchy" proposals that have been floated over the years, I think something as simple as an "implied" tag makes a lot of sense and could be done without getting unwieldy or adding undesirable complexity. I envision something like the moderator-only option to set the default syntax highlighting engine for a tag: a similar option could be provided to set an "implied" tag for that particular tag. Moderators could be trusted not to misuse the feature (e.g., to only use it for language-specific tags), and to only use in consultation with the community (specifically, domain experts).

In the mean time, please just continue to add the "master" language tag to questions where it is appropriately implied by version-specific tags.

And do note that your first concern, about watchers of version-specific tags, is partially mitigated by the fact that the "favorite" tag system (and certainly the tag filters) support wildcards, so you can just watch `[c++*]` to get everything juicy. (Is C++ juicy? Maybe thorny is a better adjective. You'll get everything thorny this way.)

Comment: Wow, didn't knew about wildcards in tags. Living and learning (Is that an expression in English?). Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, that there's a cheaper solution that requires 0 developer time since it's already implemented: tag synonym.

Comment: @Braiam - A synonym is not appropriate here. There are plenty of questions about the specification in a *specific* revision. Furthermore, some behaviors change *between* revisions. If everything becomes lumped together things can become very confusing for future readers. Plus, it will make searching for things about a specific revision much much harder.

Comment: Using the `[c++*]` tag works well for C++; not so well for C if you have to use `[c*]`!  It isn't a complete answer for all languages, though it may well work for some.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica which doesn't matter once it's considered standard on the language. Think about it. Header only libraries, before it was introduced, and now? Would you use [c++-*] for a question asked today about those? Unlikely. Tags are supposed to be about topics never asked before, something that was included into the language, only has novelty the first year, afterwards, it's just considered part of the whole.

Comment: @Braiam - No, tags are about topics, period. Not just about topics you or I consider relevant. And yes, I *would* use a tag about C++14 for instance, because my shop hasn't moved on from it yet. Not everyone gets the shiniest toys the moment they are released. Since it makes perfect sense to keep the borland-c++ tag, on account of some unfortunate souls being saddled with it, it makes no sense to get rid of standard version tags, let alone recent ones. Not everyone can simply "move on". There are ABI considerations that force compiler selection. That in turn limits standard version.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica no, despite the name tags are categories and the guidance on creation literally says "you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a **strong case** that your question covers a **new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**". The case of version tags is weak, since it causes more problems that whatever they are meant to solve and there are simpler way to do the same function: question title and body for example.

Comment: @Braiam - Applying the guidance for tag *creation* retroactively is, quite frankly, asinine. There definitely was a case for their creation, and they served (and continue to serve) their purpose well. Whatever mess version tags caused in other tags, I haven't witnessed in C++. You may argue this isn't worth developer time, but that is another issue. A ham fisted solution is no solution at all. Synonyms need to improve questions they affect, not make a mess of them.

Comment: @Braiam: I don't think adding pseudo tags in the tile and body of the question to serve as a replacement for version-tags is a good idea. This will make a mess.It might be a personal preference, but for me having real tags for the versions makes things more readable than having tons of titels like `[C++11][Qt4] How can I achive that thing` everywhere.

Comment: I suspect the wildcards would not work very well on the C tag. [tag:c*] :D

Answer (score 9):

> Should the [c++] tag be mandatory for posts with c++ language version tags?

Yes. The present policy/community consensus is that all C++ (and C) posts are about the currently active language standard, unless a specific [c++nn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bnn) tag is also used together with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Long time ago, I think I was one of the people originally behind the phrase/policy:

> Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C++ standard is used, it is assumed that the current version is used. That is, whichever version of ISO 14882 that ISO currently lists as active.

An identical policy exists for the C tag. So if you are interested in C++03 specifically, you should tag your question [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03). Otherwise, if you just use [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) then ISO/IEC 14882:2017 is assumed. Until the point where C++2x goes live and C++17 is withdrawn.

And the other way around: there might not be many people interested in C++03 specifically, particularly since it is now an older version. So it is unlikely that you will reach the experts of C++03 by just using [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03). It is very likely that you reach them if you add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) however. But I think it's mainly a matter about if you want your question to get maximum exposure and more/better answers, rather than a hard rule.

Some of the standard-specific tags do require in their tag usage wiki that the main language tag should be used. This appears to be the case at least for for all C ones, but not all C++ ones.

Your dupe hammer argument is relevant. However, I don't think we must start some retagging campain to add [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) to old posts. Doing so is mostly relevant to new posts that lack the main [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag for whatever reason.

> Is it a good idea to make c++ be automatically added to any post with a language version tag?

Sounds like a good idea indeed, if it can be done.

Also, please note that it is is important that we keep C and C++ tag usage policies in sync. So if something should (not) be done with C++ tags, the same should (not) be done with all the C tags.

Comment: Yes, I think that the same thing could be done for c, and it does make sense to keep their policies in sync. I didn't want to make the question broader than needed, but it's a good point.

Comment: Not that I'm against it, but what exactly is the reasoning here that must be in sync?

Comment: @Chipster Main reason is the cross-tagging between C and C++ which has always been a big problem. It may also be relevant to keep tag usage in sync for questions comparing the two languages. Other than that, the two language standards tend to be updated in sync nowadays: there was C11 and C++11 at the same time, C17 and C++17, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea, but it is unsupported by the platform.

So right now, just add that tag when you see it missing. If there are already five tags, try to remove the least important tag. You could also consider changing a [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) to just [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). But be careful. Sometimes it's important for the problem, and sometimes the tag is there just because OP was using C++14.