# Mass tagging request: add [c++] to questions tagged [c++98], [c++03], etc

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

There is strong consensus that the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag should be applied to all questions marked with the version specific tags [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98), [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), [c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23), and [c++26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26).

This rule has been followed perfectly for the more recent tags [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) and [c++26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26), however, older language versions don't always follow this. Here are the numbers:

| Tag | Total amount | Untagged amount | Percentage tagged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) | 683 | 60 | 91.22% |
| [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) | 808 | 48 | 94.06% |
| [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) | 55,517 | 7,724 | 86.09% |
| [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) | 8,479 | 633 | 92.53% |
| [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) | 10,737 | 624 | 94.19% |
| [c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) | 4,947 | 99 | 97.99% |
| [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) | 202 | 0 | 100.00% |
| [c++26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b26) | 7 | 0 | 100.00% |
| [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (provided out of interest) | 799,812 | 730,589 (refers to C++ questions with no version tag) | 8.64% |

As you can see, there is a gradual consensus shift to always tagging the question [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no matter the language version. This consensus is now unanimous and perfect for [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) and more recent.

#### What's up with [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) and [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)?

[c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) and [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) are anomalies because developers prior to C++11 didn't think of the language as "C++98", they just thought of it as "C++", and no tagging was required.
It is more likely for a question to have started out as [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and to then have the [c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) tag added retroactively.

#### Why mass-tag these questions retroactively?

This makes questions more discoverable. You can simply search `[c++] something` and it will bring up a C++ answer, regardless of the language version.
For questions tagged [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), there is a 14% chance that this form of searching will fail, and that is unfortunate.

#### What if a question already has five tags?

In such a case, automatic tagging cannot be performed.
However, it seems to be fairly rare that a question has e.g. [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and no [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, but still has five tags in total.

Out of the 100 newest [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) questions, 18 have five tags. If this pattern of ~20% generally holds true, it still means that the overwhelming majority can be tagged automatically with no tag removals.

---

Note that I'm not actually sure if there exists a system for these mass tag chances that can automatically add tags. If it is not possible, maybe it could be a useful community project to tag old gems that are missing [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: Or you could just search for [`c++* something`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+something). Which would provide results from all versions (and some other non-version tags though)

Comment: This type of systematic retagging would require Stack Overflow developer involvement. This conditional retagging is not something that moderator tools can assist with.

Comment: @HenryEcker do you see developer involvement as out of the question?

Comment: It's certainly not out of the question. With enough community support it's definitely something that could be put on their radar. I was more trying to communicate that this would be a special request outside of the standard and our (community and site moderators) options to directly assist with this request are rather limited.

Comment: In terms of questions with 5 tags, it appears there are [1720 questions (as of the current SEDE data)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1787097) tagged with 5 tags including at least one of the 8 version-specific c++ tags listed here, but not c++. Also here's [a SEDE query that generates the tagged/untagged table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1787106) you have at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the C++ tag should be added to these questions, but *only* if it can be carried out in a non-intrusive way by diamond moderators or CMs, so we don't end up "bumping" half the site.

Community consensus already exists, these rules were previously already discussed here (among other places), with clear community consensus:
[Should the [c++] tag be mandatory for posts with C++ language version tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402084/should-the-c-tag-be-mandatory-for-posts-with-c-language-version-tags)

As for posts that already have 5 tags, these would likely have to be edited manually by those with domain knowledge of the C++ tag. I'd say that gold/silver [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) badges and full edit privileges are strongly recommended for anyone who would participate in such an exercise.

I would imagine that other major language tags have a similar situation, [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and so on.