# Merge [c++-templates] into [templates]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I have discovered that there is a [c++-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) tag, with **59** questions. The popularity of this tag is dwarfed by the combination [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates), with **33,855** questions. I believe it is appropriate to re-tag all [c++-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) questions with [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) for the following reasons:

1. From what I remember, the community doesn't think favorably of fragmenting tags into several language-specific tags.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>
2. The [c++-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) tag is so uncommon that it's virtually useless for searches. If someone is interested in questions about C++ templates, they almost certainly won't be searching for this tag.
3. It is not adding any value compared to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates), since the community agrees on applying [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) to all C++ questions, even version-specific ones like [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23). See [Should the [c++] tag be mandatory for posts with C++ language version tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402084/5740428). Therefore, C++23 templates questions should be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [c++23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates).

---

Note that the [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) tag is somewhat ambiguous and problematic. It doesn't necessarily refer to C++ templates, even when [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is applied. A [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml) [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) question could refer to YAML templates, used somehow via a C++ API for YAML.

A migration from [c++-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) is therefore a slight loss of information for those 59 questions. Due to the enormous size of the [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) tag, it's unclear what kind of improvement could be made to it automatically, if any.

Comment: "templates" seems to be a mess of a tag.

Comment: @yivi yeah, it is a bit of a mess because it's pretty ambiguous until combined with a language tag. Nevertheless, it's what the community chose as a tag for almost 34,000 questions. Maybe we could re-tag the other way around to improve the situation, but that would be a massive change.

Comment: Before considering this merge, I'd say [tag:templates] needs a disambiguation. (Note: That tag is not C++ exclusive, there are 20,754 questions currently without the C++ tag)

Comment: I think this merge shouldn't happen, instead we should only disambiguate templates and possibly blacklist the tag because it will be recreated. The tag is too ambiguous to be useful, document templates have little to do with code templates, and there's some other stuff in there too.

Comment: Merging this seems like a step in the exact wrong direction. [tag:templates] is way too broad by itself...

Comment: @ErikA [templates] is not too ambiguous to be useful either. [c++] [templates] almost always refers to C++ templates. I generally agree that [templates] could be improved in theory, but I find it hard to imagine how that could be done in practice, seeing that the tag is applied to tens of thousands of questions. You're also describing burnination, but [templates] does not satisfy the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/5740428).

Comment: That the "templates" tag cannot be used unambiguously on its own, shows that it's too ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, but it is not "too ambiguous to be useful". That was the claim. In any case, I think we agree that [templates] does have some issues, **and it would be more useful if we could propose something to do about it.**

Comment: Yes, it's too ambiguous to be useful, since it cannot be used to connect experts with questions. The tag, combined with anything else, would have a completely different meaning.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm not describing burnination, I'm describing disambiguation, splitting up one tag into multiple more specific tags... That it's hard to do does not mean we shouldn't do it. If a tag can refer to multiple things and is only clear sometimes within specific contexts doesn't mean it shouldn't be disambiguated, it means exactly the opposite. It does mean it shouldn't be burninated.

Comment: Reminder that comments are there to ask for clarification and add new information to posts. If you don't like the idea and have a better one, add an answer to this Q&A.

Comment: "templates" can have meanings that are not even remotely analogous to the C++ meaning. The latter is just an implementation of *type parameterization*; but in **many** other contexts, "template" *doesn't refer to the code at all*, but rather to a pattern of data which is used to facilitate generating output. If anything, most (certainly not all) questions that have the `[c++] [templates]` combination, should be corrected to `[c++] [c++-templates]` instead. And yes, it is *perfectly* appropriate for question to be tagged like `[language] [language-feature]`.

Comment: Y'all, it was said above, but if you're proposing a solution, _post an answer_ so that it can be voted on and discussed.  Obviously the solution in the question is unpopular, but what should we do about the problem? ("We should do nothing, it's fine" is a valid answer if you think that)

Answer (score 16):

[templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) is used for a wide variety of subjects. These include at least:

- Generic programming templates
- Document/text templates, often filled in by templating engines
- UI/layout templates, mostly synonymous with themes, used by many CMSes and UI frameworks
- IDE templates, as in premade code/directory structures which can be provided by an IDE

Tags, as defined by the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), should primarily be used to categorize questions. If a tag can only be interpreted when taken together with other tags, and only with moderate accuracy (one can use templating engines and IDE templates in C++), that's not very useful ways to categorize questions.

Ideally, this tag should be disambiguated into more specific tags. [c++-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-template) could be one of those, as it would be more intuitive that's limited to generic programming templates to askers.

Disambiguating this tag, however, would be a major task, one where a CM probably could lend a hand and perform a mass retag for questions tagged [c++-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-template) (and quite possibly some others too). Chances we'll get CM participation for a mass retag is slim, the last one I can think of was the *-vba situation.

Of course, at that time we should have the community decide if [c++-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-template) is the way to go, or to have a common unambiguous tag for templating in the generic programming sense. We have various other language/framework + template/templating, most of which refer to generic programming, but certainly not all. And then there's the whole mess about [templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templating), [templating-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templating-engine), [document-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-template) and others. Also, [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template)[metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metaprogramming) vs [template-meta-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-meta-programming). Not something I have a strong opinion on, except that if we want to disambiguate we should make a well thought-out plan and not merge randomly (oh, and metaprogramming not meta-programming because the second is for when you've landed a job at Meta).

Since merging [c++-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-templates) into [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates) is a step towards making questions more, not less ambiguous, I think we shouldn't take it and leave the status quo, until such time as we get CMs that are invested in the proper usage of tags, or some group of users gets really motivated to improve this situation. Until then, the best we can do is not make it worse imo.

Comment: Ideally, we would manage to split up [templates] into a number of unambiguous tags. I'm really not sure how realistic such an attempt would be though. There's also the problem that [templates] would need to be burninated and blacklisted, otherwise we would get a sea of users who keep using [templates] even though [c++-templates] exists. I don't think a "DO NOT USE" notice or any other half-measure would be enough. That is, even if we get some mass re-tagging to [c++-templates]. Overall, I agree, I just don't have a lot of faith into [templates] being fixed due to the huge challenge.

Comment: As a first step, should we perhaps add a DO NOT USE notice to [templates] in the context of C++ and advise the community to use [c++-templates] instead? It's a minuscule step in the right direction at least.

Comment: @JanSchultke why limit it to C++, if we are doing that just add a general "DO NOT USE" then? Note that tag is also used for [tag:go-templates], [tag:django-templates], [tag:jinja2], and various other things that do have suitable tags of their own.

Comment: @JanSchultke Burnination is not needed here. Burnination is cleaning up an off topic tag, closing and removing bad questions, and retagging good ones. This tag isn't off-topic. We'd just need to disambiguate, then possibly blacklist or assign a synonym. There's no reason to assume that this tag attracts poor/off topic questions, so no need to thoroughly investigate whether each question should be removed. This opens up the possibility of bulk retags and removes the majority of the work associated with burnination.